# get all commit of a file/path with rugged

Tags: ruby, rugged

I would like to get the list of all the commits for a file/path but I don't know how to do it.

For example I want all the commit of the file "test", to get oid of each commit and thanks to this oid, I will get the blob of all revision for this file.

Is it possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: git log <path> will show you the commits for a specific path, you could use this.

Comment: But your solution is for git, not rugged

Comment: In that case look at the answers to this earlier question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302073/access-git-log-data-using-ruby-rugged-gem

Answer (score 1):

We can get all commits by this way :

```
      tab = []
      walker = Rugged::Walker.new(repo)
      walker.sorting(Rugged::SORT_DATE)
      walker.push(repo.head.target)
      walker.each do |commit|
        if commit.diff(paths: ["path_of_file"]).size > 0
           tab.push(commit)
        end
      end
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this way will step through all commits in the entire repository and then filter on file path - so it will scale linearly to how many commits there are in your repo.

Comment: Yes, I know, but unfortunatly it's the only solution I found.